# How to disable widget css class?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm developing a wp theme and I've maded a custom style css or the plugin [social count plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-count-plus/)
.
This class working nice but there is a problem, the plugin load an own css that will bug my style, in particular there is the file "counter.css" (that I can't prevent to load 'cause there is other style too that the user can choice), this file contains class something like this:

```
.social-count-plus a {
-moz-transition: all .4s ease;
-o-transition: all .4s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
transition: all .4s ease;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
opacity: 1;
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

I need to remove completely this class without edit the plugin, is a way for do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this plugin to change the order that the CSS stylesheets are loaded.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/re-order-css-and-js-loading-order/

Or you  can set priority to your stylesheet to make sure it is loaded after the other one.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218610/give-priority-to-child-theme-stylesheet

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fruitful_load_child_stylesheets', 20 );
```

Then after making sure that your custom style sheet is being loaded after the other stylesheet you can use important on your style tags to override the previous styles.

```
.social {
    color: red!important;
}
```

You can also use inherit to set styles to their default.

```
.social {
    display: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
function wp1232_remove_class() {
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery(".widget .social-count-plus").removeClass("social-count-plus");
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wp1232_remove_class');
```

Comment: this will remove also my css

Comment: You can add own class on this: ` jQuery(".widget .social-count-plus").removeClass("social-count-plus").addClass('my-social-count-plus');`